# How to make Azure Function triggered by Azure Event Grid with a binding to Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

Trying to remake the [Azure Grid Image Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event) example in c# using visual studio but having issues making the azure function trigger be triggered by the event grid and bind to the blob storage.

Current Code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

namespace FunctionApp
{
    public static class CreateIndex
    {
        [FunctionName("CreateIndex")]
        [StorageAccount("backup_STORAGE")]
        public static void Run(
            [EventGridTrigger()] EventGridEvent myEvent, 
            [Blob("{data.url}")] CloudBlockBlob inputBlob, 
            TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info(myEvent.ToString());
            log.Info(inputBlob.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Generated function.json:

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator-1.0.6",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "myEvent"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/FunctionApp.dll",
  "entryPoint": "FunctionApp.CreateIndex.Run"
}
```

The binding is working for the event grid trigger but not the Blob input.

Expected function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "EventGridTrigger",
      "name": "myEvent",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "inputBlob",
      "path": "{data.url}",
      "connection": "myblobstorage_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Precompiled functions generate `function.json` for you, but they only put trigger binding inside of it. It's OK that your blob binding is not in this file.

The input Blob binding will still work: runtime will pick it up based on your attributes.